# Edit a cell using its relative Position within a given Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am beginning in excel vba and I ran into a problem as I am trying to select a `cell` from a `range` based on its position within this `range`.

More specificaly my goal is to let the user key in a `range` (in A5) and then put all the values of this range to 10 except the top left cell that must be 23. My first guess was to do like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim enteredValue As String
    enteredValue = Range("A5").Text
    Dim focusArea As Range
    Set focusArea = Range(enteredValue)
    focusArea.Value = 10
    facusArea.Cells(1, 1).Value = 23
End Sub
```

But I get an error

> 424 "object required"

Therefore does anyone of you have a tip about how to do such kind of operation within a given range?

Comment: You misspelled focusArea in the last line.

Comment: The last line is a mistype. You've used `facusArea`, not `focusArea`. Another good reason to always use `Option Explicit` in your declarations area of the code sheet (Tools ► Options ► Editor ► Require Variable Declarations).

Answer (score 0):

The last line is a mistype. You've used `facusArea`, not `focusArea`. Another good reason to always use `Option Explicit` in your declarations area of the code sheet (Tools ► Options ► Editor ► Require Variable Declarations).

This question can likely be closed for the following reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

However, I wanted to offer a no-variable alternative to what you are trying to accomplish using a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to identify the range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Range(Range("A5").Text)
        .Value = 10
        .Cells(1).Value = 23
    End With
End Sub
```